# Javascript math different to what I thought it should be

Tags: javascript

Just wondering if someone knows what is wrong with my javascript math script below:

```
var new_total = (document.getElementById('qty').value * document.getElementById('pricepermetre').value) + document.getElementById('delivery').value
```

Basically it should be (1 x 10) + 2 = 12

But the script above is adding the delivery value to the end like (1 x 10) + 2 = 102

Here is the the full test page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>TEST</title>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <table class="mytable">
      <tr>
        <td>QTY:</td>
        <td><input name="qty" type="text" id="qty" style="width:70px;" value="0" maxlength="9" />
          KG </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>PRICE PER KG (EX TAX):</td>
        <td>$
          <input name="pricepermetre" type="text" id="pricepermetre" style="width:70px;" value="0" maxlength="9" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>DELIVERY FEE (EX TAX):</td>
        <td>$
          <input name="delivery" type="text" id="delivery" style="width:70px;" value="0" maxlength="9" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TOTAL (EX TAX):</td>
        <td><span id="totalpricespan">$0</span>
          <input name="totalprice" type="hidden" id="totalprice" style="width:70px;" value="0" maxlength="9" />
          <span style="color:#999;">(qty x price per kg + delivery fee)</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="button" name="WorkOutTotals" id="WorkOutTotals" value="Work Out Totals" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#WorkOutTotals').click( function() {

        //work out new total
        var new_total = (document.getElementById('qty').value * document.getElementById('pricepermetre').value) + document.getElementById('delivery').value

        $("#totalprice").val(new_total);
        $("#totalpricespan").html('$' + new_total);

    });

    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: it seems you are concatenating string, not adding numbers

Comment: Nearly all the answers here (including mine originally) assumed the numbers were whole numbers (integers), but [nnnnnn](http://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn) kindly asked me on my answer "what if the string holds a decimal?" so I've updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8562056/157247) to cover that as well -- which I suspect is important, because I wouldn't be surprised if the price **is** a decimal (e.g., "0.20" or similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-59351919) property of elements that have it (`input` elements and the like) is a *string*. Now, JavaScript will try to do what you want by converting the string to a number intrinsically, but it can't guess at your intent, and specifically when one side of the `+` operator is a number and the other side is a string, the engine will assume you want to convert the number to a string and *concatenate*, rather than assuming you want to convert the other string to a number and *add*.

To properly convert a string to a number, use `parseInt` (and specify the radix) for whole numbers or `parseFloat` for fractional numbers expressed in decimal. So if these are whole numbers:

```
var new_total = (
      parseInt(document.getElementById('qty').value, 10) *
      parseInt(document.getElementById('pricepermetre').value, 10)
    ) +
    parseInt(document.getElementById('delivery').value, 10);
```

Or if they're decimals:

```
var new_total = (
      parseFloat(document.getElementById('qty').value) *
      parseFloat(document.getElementById('pricepermetre').value)
    ) +
    parseFloat(document.getElementById('delivery').value);
```

Note that there's no radix parameter on `parseFloat`; the number is always expected to be in base 10 decimal.

Relying on JavaScript's rules for when it should "coerce" strings to numbers is usually a bad idea, not least because you need to be sure to control the radix and such.

Comment: What if the string in question holds a decimal?

Answer (score 4):

`document.getElementById('delivery').value` returns a string, and you'll end with string concatenation since `+` is used by JS to concat string.

*update*

JavaScript's `+` has different meaning depending on what you use. Amazingly, `*` can multiply even if the number is shown as string.

try this

```
// `*` will infer that you wanted multiplication
alert("2" * 2);
alert("2" * 2);
alert(2 * "2");
alert(2 * 2);

// however, the `+` may take addition or string concatenation
alert("1" + "0");
alert("1" + 0);
alert(1 + "0");
alert(1 + 0);
```

[sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/83kYM/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `parseInt(document.getElementById('delivery').value).` You've got a problem with casting (or type inference, whatever).

Comment: You should specify a radix of 10 for the second pararmeter to `parseInt()`, especially when dealing with user input.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript engine is confusing strings and numbers, try:

`var new_total = (document.getElementById('qty').value) * document.getElementById('pricepermetre').value) + parseInt(document.getElementById('delivery').value);`

Comment: *"The JavaScript engine is confusing strings and numbers"* No, it isn't. The coder is.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this does the job

```
var new_total = parseInt((document.getElementById('qty').value * document.getElementById('pricepermetre').value)) + parseInt(document.getElementById('delivery').value)
```

Comment: The first `parseInt()` is redundant given you're passing it the result of a numeric operation. Also, especially when user input is involved, you should specify a radix of 10 for the second parameter to `parseInt()`.

Answer (score 1):

You're dealing with strings, not numbers. Use `parseInt()` to get the number before arithmetics.

Answer (score 1):

Value in fields is of string type. When you multiply the values are implicity converted to numbers, but when you use `+` operator it's casted to string (because 2 is string). Use `parseFloat` or `parseInt` to convert text to number.

Answer (score 1):

```
var new_total = (
                parseInt(document.getElementById('qty').value, 10) *
                parseInt(document.getElementById('pricepermetre').value, 10)
                )
                +
                parseInt(document.getElementById('delivery').value, 10);
```

You get strings from those values. Convert them to numbers and then do your math on 'em. With the `+` on strings, you're just concatenating them.

I'm using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) here, with a radix parameter of 10, that forces the string to be converted to a number in base 10. So, say, `010` becomes `10` instead of `8` (octal). You may instead want to use `parseFloat` to get decimal places as well.